# Is SavedStateHandle in ViewModel and currentBackStackEntry the same?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation, android-savedstate, viewmodel-savedstate

I want to pass some data using savedStateHandle from activity straight to fragment's viewModel.

In my **activity** I have:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
    controller.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set(
        "foo",
         "bar"
    )
}
```

So code in **viewModel** looks like:

```
MyViewModel(state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        state
            ?.getStateFlow("foo", "")
            ?.onEach { /* do something */ }
            ?.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
```

And for some reason expected `bar` value never get emitted.

I've checked in **Fragment** itself, and data is there:

```
val handle = findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle

handle?.getLiveData<String>("foo")?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    // here it is

}
```

But is there any possibility to pass data right to the viewModel's savedStateHandle?
I believe should be, since navagrs are passed somehow.